# Insert a row in table have one to many and many to one

Tags: java, jpa

I have 3 entities with one to many and many to one relationship as (please attention in red box):
The first entity named **KhachHang**:

[image: The first table name KhachHang]

The second entity named **ThamDu**

[image: the second entity]

The third entity named **MaSoThuong**

[image]

Please help me insert a row into table **ThamDu**.

Comment: Please stop tagging JPA questions with JSF. This has nothing to do with JSF. JSF is just a web MVC API, not a persistence API.

Comment: By the way, how exactly is this different from your previous question on the same subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899263/insert-into-table-with-2-forgein-key-on-it ? Please don't repost the same question over and over. Instead edit and improve the question based on the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you don't get sufficient or satisfiable respons.